# Continuous integration for single files

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I need to define a continuous integration process for a project that contains multiple config files or scripts.

I am used to work with java projects where each "deployable" was a different git repo, so every commit to the repo could trigger a build and deploy.

The problem I am facing now is that I have a git repo that contains independent shell scripts and config files (all of them related to the same project that's why are under the same git repo) but I want to deploy them independently

For instance imagine this folder structure:

- repo/sourceA/config.conf
- repo/sourceA/scriptA.sh
- repo/sourceB/config.conf
- repo/sourceB/scriptB.sh

If a change is done in scriptA.sh, I don't want to re-deploy anything from sourceB as it hasn't changed.

Is there any "standard" way of doing this kind of deployments?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your using pipeline to build you projects ...If so, when a check in is done read the commit from the git hook payload, so the commit will have a message like so "made changes to script A" then you can use a simple if condition and execute script A only

hope this helps :)

Comment: @Javier S  if this helped you in solving your issue please select it as the correct answer so that others, who face this issue will know what needs to be done

Comment: I don't really like the idea of reading the commit message... but you gave me an idea.. see files modified in the commit and deploy those